# Fixing up a rusty old Rallye mountain bike

Tags: chain, repair, derailleur-rear, rust, restoration

I bought a Rallye mountain bike from Facebook Marketplace last year and did most of the major overhauling then as well. It was covered in mud, gunk, rust, had broken pedals, etc. So I had replaced the grips, pedals, brake cables and scoured as much rust off of it as I could.

Now that I've finally had time to work on it again I've found it's rusted again (it's been sitting outside exposed to the elements, I know it shouldn't be kept out there). The brake handles are cracked worse than they were when I got it so I ordered a new pair since it prevents me from actually using my brakes they're due to arrive in a couple days, and I haven't been able to shift since I've gotten it so I'm trying to figure out how to get the derailleurs working again, there's significant slack in the cables.

In all honesty, I'm a bit of a newb pertaining to bikes but it seems simple enough since I've gotten a handle on the bare basics. Any and all help or listed resources will be awesome.

Comment: In short I'm asking how do I get the tension right for the cables in my derailleurs and getting them working again.

Comment: Alrighty, so I worked on it a bit after watching a few videos and finally got all gears functioning. Was able to remove most of the rust on the chain with a chain cleaner device and tooth brush. WD-40 worked really well to get the gunk and ikk off then filled the chain cleaner with water and a bit of Dawn.

Comment: Politely, after all the work you are putting into this bike, find a way to store it inside.  Leaving it outside is not helping you.